# In Xamarin.Android/iOS how to keep some button/menu/control always visible in each mobile screen

Tags: xamarin, controls, screen, visible

On Android/iOS, is it possible to make some menu, button or control in fixed position, and have it always visible and available in each mobile screen?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.

What have you tried and how do you want it to look like? Your question is being down voted right now because you're not giving us very much info to work with :)

I'm going to assume that you are willing to use Xamarin.Forms. Then look at the [MasterDetailPage, NavigationPage and/or TabbedPage](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/pages/) this will probably provide you with the layout you want.